# Perl Calculate netmask from CIDR

Tags: perl, subnet, cidr, netmask

I found a little function on a website here 
http://jmorano.moretrix.com/2010/08/calculate-netmask-in-perl
I am using it, but it does not produce the same thing as he gets.

I am putting a CIDR address in a variable like this :

```
126.126.126.250/24
```

The function should return something like 
`255.255.255.0`
But instead, it returns

```
0.0.0.255
```

The only thing that i modified in the function is

```
my($network, $netbit) = split ///, $subnet;
```

TO

```
my($network, $netbit) = split /\//, $subnet;
```

and the return is just changed into "print"
`return $netmask;` TO   `print "$netmask \n" ;`

I guess there's something wrong in here

```
    my $_bit         = ( 2 ** (32 - $netbit) ) - 1;
```

Because when i print $_bit i just have "255"

But i can't figure what is it.

Comment: I found that the code does a lot of extra processing. One extra invocation of `pack` and `unpack` could've been removed with an extra shift. Eg. `perl -e '$b=24; $m=(2**$b-1)<<(32-$b); print join(".", unpack("C4",pack("N",$m)));'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more backslash needed,

```
my ($full_mask)  = unpack( "N", pack( "C4", split(/\./, '255.255.255.255') ) );
                                                   ^
```

although it would make more sense as

```
my ($full_mask)  = unpack( "N", pack( "C4", 255,255,255,255 ) );
```

or

```
my ($full_mask)  = unpack( "N", pack( "C4", (255) x4 ) );
```

Comment: Sorry to annoy, but what if i want to calculate the subnet address ? should i do $netmask & $network ?

Comment: Yes, something in that sense.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing your own function, consider using an existing module like [`Net::Netmask`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Netmask/lib/Net/Netmask.pod):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Net::Netmask;

my $cidr = '126.126.126.250/24';
my $block = Net::Netmask->new2( $cidr ) or die $Net::Netmask::error;
say $block->mask;
```

#### Output:

```
255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 3):

A smaller alternative to the link in the question:

```
sub _smaller_calc_netmask {
    my($subnet) = @_;

    # e.g.: 10.0.0.0/24 192.168.1.0/16
    my($network, $netbit) = split m'/', $subnet; # quote as match delimiter hack  

    # Decimal representation of mask
    my $mask  = (2 ** $netbit - 1) << (32 - $netbit); 

    # convert decimal representation to our familiar form
    my $netmask = join( '.', unpack( "C4", pack( "N", $mask ) ) );

    return $netmask;
}
```